# Android layout issue - relative widths in percent using weight

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to assign relative widths to columns in a ListView that is in a TabHost, using layout_weight as suggested [here](https://andmobidev.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-width-of-view-using-percentage.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">
           <TableLayout  
              android:id="@+id/triplist" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:paddingTop="4px">
              <TableRow>
                 <ListView android:id="@+id/triplistview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>
                 <Button android:id="@+id/newtripbutton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add Trip"/>
              </TableRow>
[other tabs ...]
```

My row definition has 4 columns that I would like to size as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="1.0"
   android:padding="4px">   
   <TextView android:id="@+id/rowtripdate"
      android:layout_weight=".2"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="date"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/rowodostart"
      android:layout_weight=".2"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/rowodoend"
      android:layout_weight=".2"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/rowcomment"
      android:layout_weight=".4"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Unfortunately, it seems to want to fit all the columns into the space that the button occupies, as opposed to the width of the screen. Or maybe there is another constraint that I do not understand. I'd appreciate your help.

[image]
<sub>(source: [heeroz.com](http://heeroz.com/layoutprob.png))</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I forgot this property for the TableLayout element:

```
android:stretchColumns="0"
```

It appears to be working now.

Comment: I'd change from px to dip in your layouts to support different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you are showing there.  To get a better picture of what is going on, you might try out the [heirarchy viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html).  It comes with the SDK.  It will visualize for you how much space each of the "hidden" layers is taking, so you can figure out which one decided to only be that big.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had not known this tool. I found that the ListView (136px) does not fill the entire width of the table row (480px), but why is a different question. 136px also happens to be the width of the button.